# Set result from python script into a variable in makefile

Tags: python, makefile

```
python ./folder/script.py ; result=$$?; echo "$$result"
```

the echo result is 0 or 1

How can i set the value of $$result in a variable to use in the following if/else:

My Make file Command:

```
deploy/run:

$(shell python ./folder/script.py)

ifeq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)
    export TF_VAR_DB_NAME='some_db'
else
    export TF_VAR_DB_NAME='other_db'
endif
```

My script.py basics is:

```
class TaskChecker(object):
    @staticmethod
    def run():
        matches = True
        if matches:
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TaskChecker.run()
```

GNU Make 3.81

Comment: this export is for Terraform in travis.

Comment: I've added another example to my answer showing that this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your Python code to print to stdout, you can suck up the text directly:

```
result := $(shell python ./folder/script.py)
```

If you really need just the exit code, this should work:

```
$(shell python ./folder/script.py)
ifeq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),1)
    echo "YEY"
else
    echo "OHNO"
endif
```

GNU Make 3.81

***Update***

Here's an example showing that this works:

```
C:\tmp>cat Makefile
$(shell python -c "import sys\; sys.exit(1)")

ifeq ($(.SHELLSTATUS), 0)
    export LEFT = 123
else
    export LEFT = 456
endif

all:
    python -c "import os; print(os.environ['LEFT'])"

C:\tmp>make
python -c "import os; print(os.environ['LEFT'])"
456

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: i get this error make: result: No such file or directory when try to result := $

Comment: You said you wanted this in a makefile, right?  Did I misunderstand?  The lines I showed there are designed to go in a makefile.

Comment: u are correct, but when i try do use the first option u give, i receive this error: `result: No such file or directory `

Comment: That tells me you're typing this at a shell prompt or in a shell script, not in a makefile.

Comment: something is wrong, i get this error when i run in my console `make deploy/run`

Comment: Then perhaps you should show us the makefile.

Comment: I add my makefile code, and my py script to be more clear.